# Java Card Connecting To a Simulator failed

Tags: java, javacard, apdu

I am trying to test a Java Card applet to establish a connection to a simulator such as cref:

```
try {
    sckClient = new Socket("localhost", 9025);
    InputStream is = sckClient.getInputStream();
    OutputStream os = sckClient.getOutputStream();
    cad = CadDevice.getCadClientInstance(CadDevice.PROTOCOL_T0, is, os);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("error");
    return;
}

try {
    cad.powerUp();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (CadTransportException e) {
    System.out.println("error");
    try {
        sckClient.close();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return;
}
```

My code get stuck in `powerUp` without any error or exception.
I am using the *sample_device* and *sample_platform* that comes with **Java Card Development Kit 3.0.5u1**

Comment: Why port `9025`, why protocol `T=0`? Where did you find these values? What tutorial are you following?

Comment: these values are set in the sample_device parameters

Comment: any help please ?

Comment: I did try disable it but I still can't get it work, my program hang on powerUp ()

Comment: @Anass Boukalane did u resolved ur issue? same case is with me